# Caching the results of a store query

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using a query in a route like this:

```
this.store.query('notes', { customer_id: some_id })
```

Is there a way to do this such that a reload isn't triggered every time the route is transitioned into? I understand that `findAll` and `findRecord` work like that. Once the data is fetched initially, there's a background reload every time the route is transitioned to again.

Comment: `query` means to query the server. Take a look at `filter`.

Comment: what do you mean by "cached"? all records are cached in the store.. regardless of the method used to get them

Comment: @Grapho — Oh, sorry. I meant cached in the sense that they don't reload every time that route is transitioned into. When using `findAll` or `findRecord`, that is the case. A backgroundReload is triggered, but that's fine.

Comment: @torazaburo — Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: Maybe look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-query-cache) npm module I've build. Its an ugly hack but it works.